# How do I find the relative angle between two ordered sets of points?

Tags: coordinate-systems, angle

Say I have two sets of ordered points, $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$ and $(x_4, y_4)$. I want to map the first pair of coordinates to the second pair of coordinates (so the first coordinate maps onto the third, and the second to the fourth.)

I want to find the relative rotation the second pair of coordinates has with the first. I know the relative scaling ratio of the two coordinates (essentially the ratio of the distances between the two sets of coordinates). How can I go about finding the angle between the two?

[image: Example of what I mean]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show us a picture of the two segments that marks the angle you want to calculate?

Comment: @EthanBolker I just made a sample image!

Comment: Does this help: [Find the rotation between set of points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186111/find-the-rotation-between-set-of-points), or [FINDING OPTIMAL ROTATION AND TRANSLATION BETWEEN CORRESPONDING 3D POINTS](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome This is very similar, and potentially really helpful! That said, I only have two points I need to find the rotation angle between, so there's no least-squares regression I should need.

Comment: With the dot product of the vectors $P2-P1$ and $P4-P3$ you can calculate the cosine of the angle (divide by the product of the lengths).